# Acessar informações de um data.frame em R

Tags: r

Estou tentando desenvolver um sistema de recomendação utilizando a linguagem R.
Basicamente, o sistema é de recomendação musical coleta informações de um arquivo onde existe uma certa quantidade de usuários e para cada usuário, uma contagem de vezes que ele ouviu determinado artista.

```
library(recommenderlab) #Bibliotecas utilizadas para carregar dados e montar recomendações
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

setwd("C:/Users/DIRETORIO/Documents/R/dados") #Local de arquivo de treinamento

dados <- fread("dadosTreinamento.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "\t", fill = TRUE) #Dados carregados em variável

names(dados)[2:3] <- c("IdArtist", "IdUser") #Renomeando colunas 2 e 3

dadosGrupo <- group_by(dados, IdUser, IdArtist) #Agrupando os dados

dadosGrupo2 <- summarise(dadosGrupo, count = n()) #Gerando tabela com soma da quantidade de vezes que cada usuário ouviu determinado artista
dadosGrupo2 <- as.data.frame(dadosGrupo2) #Convertendo dadosGrupo2 para data.frame

matrizAfinidade <- as(dadosGrupo2, "realRatingMatrix") #Matriz real de dados

Rec.model<-Recommender(matrizAfinidade, method = "UBCF")

usuarios <- length(unique(dadosGrupo2$IdUser)) #Capturando a quandidade de usuários únicos

listaRecomendacoes <- vector("list", usuarios)

for (i in 1:usuarios) {
  itemRecomendado <- predict(Rec.model, matrizAfinidade[i,], n=5)
  listaRecomendacoes[[i]] <- as((itemRecomendado), "list")
}
```

Após gerar a recomendação em:

```
for (i in 1:usuarios) {
  itemRecomendado <- predict(Rec.model, matrizAfinidade[i,], n=5)
  listaRecomendacoes[[i]] <- as((itemRecomendado), "list")
}
```

Preciso, por meio do resultado com o id do album, resgatar a linha com os dados correspondentes sobre o artista. Por exemplo: para o usuário `7687`
foi gerada a recomendação `"54"   "85"   "52"   "245"  "8035"`.
Com o id do primeiro Album do exemplo (54), preciso recuperar as informações de toda a linha correspondente.

Pesquisei muitas formas de fazer isso, porém todas ensinam por meio de endereçamento, não com o dado em si.

A base de dados está [neste link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/18CvNXblNPcrfvaD9O9I8BoPnmsreRFsQ?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a função `subset(seuDataFrame, seuDataFrame$colunaID == valorID)`, ele vai retornar a linha correspondente ao ID que você quer.

Comment: Obrigado, sanou minha dúvida.